# currency pound is shown as &pound; when exporting as csv

Tags: php, laravel, csv, export-to-csv, laravel-4.2

I need to export data as csv. Everything is getting except the currency symbol.
For eg. currency £  is shown as `&pound;`
My project is a laravel 4.2 application.

```
$filename   = $customer['firstname']."_".date('Y-m-d h:i').".csv";
$file_path  = storage_path(). "/transactions"."/".$filename;  
$handle     = fopen($file_path,"w+");
fputcsv($handle, array('Date', 'Type', 'Ticket', 'Quantity', 'Ticket type', 'Block', 'Event date', 'Paid', 'Recieved'));

foreach($ticket as $row) {
    if($row->type == 'purchased')
    {
        $p_amount = trans('homepage.currencyInUse') .' '.number_format($row->amount, 2).' '.trans('homepage.currencyAfter');
        $s_amount = ' ';
    }
    elseif($row->type == 'sold')
    {
        $p_amount = ' ';
        $s_amount = trans('homepage.currencyInUse').' '.number_format($row->amount, 2).' '.trans('homepage.currencyAfter');
    }
    fputcsv($handle, array(
            date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->orderDate)), 
            $row->type,
            $row->event->title,
            $row->qty,
            $row->ticketType,
            trans('homepage.Block').':'.$row->ticket['ticketInformation']['loc_block'] ,
            date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row->event->datetime)),
            $p_amount,
            $s_amount,
        )
    );
}

fclose($handle);

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
);

return Response::download($file_path, $filename, $headers);
```

This the code used to export as csv

Comment: When you are exporting try to use encode UTF-8

Comment: I have updated the questions.please check and tell me where I have to change

Comment: Try this `'Content-Type' =>  text/csv charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Where's the data coming from - from a database? Did you store "&pound;" in the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could transform HTML entities to UTF-8 characters using [`html_entity_decode()`](https://php.net/html_entity_decode):

```
$currency_use = html_entity_decode(trans('homepage.currencyInUse'), ENT_HTML5, 'utf-8');
$currency_after = html_entity_decode(trans('homepage.currencyAfter'), ENT_HTML5, 'utf-8');
if($row->type == 'purchased')
{
    $p_amount =  $currency_use.' '.number_format($row->amount, 2).' '.$currency_after;
    $s_amount = ' ';
}
elseif($row->type == 'sold')
{
    $p_amount = ' ';
    $s_amount = $currency_use.' '.number_format($row->amount, 2).' '.$currency_after;
}
```

Here is an example:

```
$currency = '&pound;';
echo $currency, PHP_EOL;
echo html_entity_decode($currency, ENT_HTML5, 'utf-8'), PHP_EOL;
```

Outputs:

```
&pound;
£
```

Comment: ┬ú  This is what i can see in the csv file

Comment: I'm just downloading the file and viewing it

Comment: In your software that you use to read it, can you change the encoding to UTF-8? You can also change the encoding of `html_entity_decode()`  (last parameter), according to your default encoding.